# How to measure the energy consumption class of a home appliance?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity, home-experiment, efficient-energy-use

Some of you may be familiar with the [EU energy consumption classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_energy_label) for domestic appliances (or equivalents in other areas).

Let's say we have a domestic appliance which was made before the energy directives were made active.

How can one measure (approximately) the energy consumption using whatever is available in one's kitchen or home and check which class the appliance could be put under?

**Clarification:**

Of course one can use a power meter an extract some results. The question is more precisely about what can one do using things (and methods) available in one's kitchen. It would be best to describe a mehod to implement this task and furthermore the method should be able to classify (approximately not laboratory precision required) the appliance in terms of the EU energy classes.

Answers that mention the power company power supply meter are in the spirit of what is asked.

Comment: @Qmechanic, i would rather have the "*efficient-energy-use*" tag intact, is this deleted (as a tag i mean)? Plus i would like your opinion in the context of these tags, since it seems nothing of the sort appears on this site and its important. The exact name of tag can be under discussion.

Comment: Don't know about your kitchen, but a power meter is definitely something available in my kitchen

Comment: Bounty refunded and question closed. This is off topic by [our policy on engineering questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4536/), as agreed upon [on meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6086/cant-close-question-with-open-bounty/6087)

Comment: I'm not especially amused to have a question closed by a moderator without any consultation. I think you should leave it up to us to vote to close if we want.

Comment: @JohnRennie I agree with you except that once a question has a bounty the community can't vote to close until the bounty period has expired.  Bounties make questions immune to community closure.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: so cancel and refund the bounty then leave it up to us to VTC. The question was open for three days before the bounty was created, so site users had plenty of time to VTC during that period. The fact they didn't suggests the community as a whole didn't want the question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement that the measurement be made with equipment available in a kitchen is a severe constraint as I can't think of any way of measuring the electrical power supplied. If it's impossible to measure the electrical power in then the only other approach is to measure the thermal power out - i.e. measure the heat produced by the appliance.

Given that thermometers are a routine part of cooking (well, confectionary cooking anyway :-) I would put the appliance in a small room. Turn it on and measure the temperature rise as a function of time. Your chances of directly relating the temperature rise to the power are close to zero as there are too many variables involved. However what you can do is compare it to a standard.

So your experimental protocol is to put a desk lamp with a known wattage in the room, turn it on and measure the temperature rise over some convenient time. Repeat using two lamps, then three, and so on, and draw a calibration curve of power vs rate of temperature rise. Now measure the temperature rise caused by the appliance, and finally read off the power from your calibration curve.

There are obvious practical problems, of which I suspect the main one is that unless the room is very small the temperature rise will be too small to be easily measured. Assuming you get round this, the next big problem is going to be standardising the conditions. Draughts need to be rigorously excluded as they will change the temperature far more than the appliance. You'll also need roughly constant ambient temperature at the beginning of the measurement. Still, you should be able to get a rough idea of the appliance power.

Once you have measured the power you can classify the device. For example, suppose you do the experiment and you measure that your dishwasher produces 1.5kW. If you look at the [EU classifications for dishwashers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_energy_label#Dishwashers) you see that category C covers the range from 1.45kW to 1.65kW, so you can conclude that your dishwasher is category C.

Different types of appliance have different categories, for example for [washing machines category C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_energy_label#Washing_machines_and_tumble_dryers) is from 0.27kW to 0.31kW. So you need to check on the web site for whatever type of appliance you're measuring.

Comment: Clever idea, but a long way to go to avoid buying or borrowing a $20 power meter.  Calorimetry will tell you real power, but I don't see a easy way to measure power factor.

Comment: +1, in the spirit of the question. yes using kitchen tools is a constraint indeed, the rational is use and combination of sound physical principles to make the best of the situation (and of course only approximate measurement is needed), thanx

Comment: any way this can be used to (approximately) classify the appliance wrt to EU energy classes?

Comment: @NikosM. Yes, because it allows you to calculate how much power the appliance consumes. The EU energy class depends on the power consumption, so once you've measured the power consumption of your appliance just look it up in the tables the EU publish to see which class it's in.

Comment: if you could add (the rest of) the method to classify this (relatively to EU classes), would make a self-contained answer.

Comment: plus i would still like to give the bounty (if this re-opens)

Answer (score 2):

You have a rather precise power meter in your home, which is a "gift" of the electrical power company. Turn off every other load that is connected to that power meter and do your measurement. Alternatively, you can invest $20 in an electronic power meter that is available online and in many stores.

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: What appliance are we talking about? A dishwasher? Fridge? Hood? Am I allowed to cut the power cord and do really dangerous stuff with it, like use pots and pans and salt water in an improvised electrolysis cell? That kind of thing?

Comment: well choose one you like, if the method provided is correct (for this appliance, in case it depends on appliance) it will be accepted. However since this is supoosed to be home-experiment take this into account when cutting power cords :)

Comment: btw (not take this as prompt rather as comment), i would expect questions of this type to be at least somewhat popular (in physics), it seems i'm wrong

Comment: I will restrain myself from making solidly dangerous propositions. If I had to read about a dead kid found in a kitchen the next day, who tried to do the "experiment", I would have a hard time living with myself.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use an energy monitor device (the most popular one seems to be the Kill-A-Watt but there are others).  They simply plug into the wall and then you plug your appliance into it.  It displays instantaneous voltage, current, power, power factor, etc. and can keep total energy over time.

Another option would be to buy an electric current sensor that clamps around a power cord.  You could use this to measure the current draw of the appliance.  Then you can either measure or assume the voltage in your home and use current and voltage to calculate power.

Comment: see the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You can only measure a part of EU compliance.  By using your utility meter and measuring the difference between the power consumed over say 10 minutes with the appliance on and off (with everything else in the house as off or steady as possible), you can measure consumed power.

However, that's just one part of EU compliance.  The other is power factor.  That is a measure of the extent that the current waveform matches the voltage waveform.  The ideal power factor is 1, which means that the current is everywhere proportional to the voltage, such as would be the case with a purely resistive load.  Real loads have reactive (capacitive or inductive) components, or draw current in pulses or erratically.

There is really no easy way to measure power factor with simple "kitchen appliance" methods.  However, meters that specifically measure real power and power factor are cheap and available.  If you really want to know, just get or borrow one of those and measure your appliance directly.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "power factor" part of the EU classifications